# LDAP filter - how to add parent groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have an LDAP filter that looks like this -
(&(objectCategory=group)(|(cn=MYGRPS*)(cn=TPM*)))

And it does work .. but my question is - what can I add to this filter (if anything), so, that except these groups I would also get back their "parent" groups. In other words, groups that have these groups (MYGRPS* and TPM*) as their members. Can this be done?

One could use - "1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941 LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN" but you have to specify a user and/or group there but how can I apply it globally? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it all in one query, since the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` OID only works with the `member` attribute, and you cannot use wildcards to match any attribute that takes a `distinguishedName` (like `member`).

So you will have to run your query as you have it right now, and then run a separate query using the `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` OID for each group that you find.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel, makes sense.